# How to read Microsoft exchange 2007 IPM.Note information

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

I have to read IPM note and get the following 2 information

1)who send mail to whom
2) which all mail still in uread state

I want to know how to do the same in c# coding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method described here: http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/09/08/FindItems-Helper-method-for-the-Exchange-Managed-API.aspx.

Just request EmailMessageSchema.DisplayTo, EmailMessageSchema.DisplayCc and EmailMessageSchema.From.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Outlook Object Model - MailItem object (wich wraps the IPM.Note messages) exposes Sender, UnRead, Recipients properties.